# Is it possible to replace jpa annotation @EntityListeners(SomeListener.class) with a custom annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

While searching for answers on my own, I did discover the Composed Annotations. That looked great, and it worked for certain kind of annotations (that I can't determine yet). I know that I want to replace only one annotation (which is @EntityListeners), but that will be great in case I have to combine other annotations in the future. Of course I tried to create a custom composed annotation but that didn't work.
Can someone explain how we could know if a specific annotation can be replaced by a custome one or not?
Is Metadata annotations has anything to do with that?
Is there a way to do this with SpringBoot since I'm using the 2.0.1-RELEASE and Spring Data JPA?